# Correct way to open/close the database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Right now I am using a static instance of the `SQLOpenHelper` class like so:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
    private final Context mContext;

    //...

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        /**
         * use the application context as suggested by CommonsWare.
         * this will ensure that you don't accidentally leak an Activity's
         * context (see this article for more information:
         * http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
         */
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    //...
}
```

And then a `DatabaseProcessor` class like so:

```
public class DatabaseProcessor {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseHelper mSQLHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public DatabaseProcessor(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mSQLHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mContext);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mSQLHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDatabase.close();
    }

   //...
}
```

So if I want to access my database, I do something like this:

```
DatabaseProcessor mDatabaseProcessor = new DatabaseProcessor(this);
mDatabaseProcessor.open();
mSomeList = mDatabaseProcessor.doSomeQueryAndReturnResults();
mDatabaseProcessor.close();
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Or is it better to open the database in the base `Activity` onResume() method and close it during onPause()? How do I correctly throw errors for situations where the database is not open when I try to run a query?

**EDIT** Refactored version:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
    private static Context mContext;

    // ...

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        /**
         * use the application context as suggested by CommonsWare.
         * this will ensure that you don't accidentally leak an Activity's
         * context (see this article for more information:
         * http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
         */
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SOME_TABLE); //some SQL expression
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        db.execSQL(DB_ALTER);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDatabase.close();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return mDatabase.isOpen();
    }

    //below this would be various CRUD functions operating on mDatabase
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Usually the answer is: you never close the database. Since database I/O needs to be done on background threads, and since you may be working with the database beyond any single activity (e.g., several activities, maybe a service or two), often times it is difficult to know when everybody is done with the database. You don't want to close it while portions of your app are still working with it.

Comment: Will keeping it open increase the risk of data corruption? I recall a while back a random Logcat error informed me that I had a leak in the database and that I should close it when it's not in use (or something to this effect)

Comment: Otherwise: I assume that in my Launcher activity, instantiate the database, `open()` it, and never call `close()` on it ever? And just use `newInstance()` anywhere I need access to the database?

Comment: "Will keeping it open increase the risk of data corruption?" -- no, SQLite is transactional. There are no unflushed buffers or anything that you need to worry about. "a random Logcat error informed me that I had a leak in the database and that I should close it when it's not in use" -- oh, in an ideal world, you would close the database. And in trivial apps, like book samples, you probably can ensure that you cover your bases and close the database properly. In the real world, including the various AOSP apps, you never close it.

Comment: "just use newInstance() anywhere I need access to the database?" -- I think you mean `getInstance()`, but yes. Depending on your app's architecture, "anywhere I need access" may not be all that many places.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just added to the OP a refactored version where everything is in one class. Is this the correct setup? Is there any harm in calling `open()` inside the place where `mInstance` is set (or perhaps in the constructor)? Wouldn't passing in the context in the future to this `getInstance()` method (e.g. another `Activity`) be ignored?

Comment: "Is this the correct setup?" -- I certainly cannot say whether it is "correct". I can say that it is a commonly-seen pattern. "Is there any harm in calling open() inside the place where mInstance is set (or perhaps in the constructor)?" -- the #1 thing is to call `open()` on a background thread, as that will trigger your `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` methods, which will involve disk I/O. Where the code resides in the class is less critical. "Wouldn't passing in the context in the future to this getInstance() method (e.g. another Activity) be ignored?" -- yes. Not a big problem.

Comment: Sorry, by "correct" I mean "the way it's set up makes sense and isn't doing anything silly"

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "background thread" -- are you are saying not to call `open()` from within the constructor or `getInstance()` method, but rather from some place elsewhere in the code (such as the Launcher `Activity`) (and you'd only have to call `.open()` here once and never anywhere else in any other `Activity`, etc)?

Comment: "the way it's set up makes sense and isn't doing anything silly" -- you might want to make `mDatabase` be `volatile`. Otherwise, that seems fine. "Not sure what is meant by "background thread"" -- um, that's a fairly fundamental concept in non-Web-browser software development. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29 and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html and just about any serious book on Android development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731611/opening-an-sqlite-database-in-a-background-thread

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put your query/transaction statements in `try-catch` and then release all your resources and close the connection in `finally` block.

```
try{
      mSomeList = mDatabaseProcessor.doSomeQueryAndReturnResults();
} catch(Exception exc){
    //Catch exceptions here
} 
finally{
    if(mDatabaseProcessor != null)
         mDatabaseProcessor.close();
}
```

Comment: Isn't catching generic exceptions considered questionable?

Comment: I just gave you an example. Definitely you need to catch  specific exceptions according to your code.