# Opening an Sqlite database in a background thread

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite, android-activity

I am trying to better understand what it means to open an Sqlite database on a background thread in Android. Right now I am using a static/singleton pattern for my database via my class `DatabaseHelper`, so I only need to open it once, but I want to open it using good practice and understand why I shouldn't open it directly from within my `Activity` directly (or within the helper's constructor, for example).

My class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static volatile SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
    private static Context mContext;

    // ...

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        /**
         * use the application context as suggested by CommonsWare.
         * this will ensure that you don't accidentally leak an Activity's
         * context (see this article for more information:
         * http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
         */
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SOME_TABLE); //some SQL expression
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        db.execSQL(DB_ALTER);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDatabase.close();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return mDatabase.isOpen();
    }

    //below this would be various CRUD functions operating on mDatabase
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Is it correct to say that you should do something like this:

```
   DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);

   Thread thread = new Thread("OpenDbThread") {
      public void run(){
        mDatabaseHelper.open();
      }
   };


   thread.start();
```

inside an `Activity` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the code you wrote would open the database on a background thread. However, you wouldn't actually the database was opened until [thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) returned false (or [mDatabase.isOpen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isOpen()) returned true). Alternatively, you could make your Activity listen for a callback from your Thread.